# "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object" MomentJS

Tags: jquery, momentjs

Having some serious issue with momentjs. I keep getting "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object" and not getting much online.

```
var startOfWeek;    
$(document).ready(function () {
      startOfWeek = moment($(".datepicker").val()).startOf("isoWeek").toDate();
    });

    function X(){
     var dateS= moment(startOfWeek).add(1, 'd');//error on moment
    }
```

What am I missing? Am I doing it wrong? Kindly assist.

Comment: function X(){ } typo?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Comment: If you're invoking `X()` outside of document ready you will run into an error, since `startOfWeek` is undefined at runtime (and only assigned when document is ready).

Comment: @Terry I edited the solution, to rule out the undefined issue.

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like that

```js
var startOfWeek = moment("2020-02-16T00:00:00");
var begin = moment(startOfWeek).startOf('week').isoWeekday(1);
console.log(begin)
// make sure startOfWeek  is string so may be you need to convert.
var new_date = moment(startOfWeek, "DD-MM-YYYY").add('days', 5).format('MMMM DD YYYY');
console.log(new_date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: true but nop its not a win.

Comment: @AneleNgqandu what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: 1. Get the first day of the week using the selected day, that you passed here var startOfWeek = moment("12-25-2020", "MM-DD-YYYY"); 2. Maybe increment the day buy 1.

Comment: also when having d=new Date() I get  Date is not a constructor. Is it maybe conflict of scripts??